# How to add custom button in existing webview android?

Tags: javascript, android

I want to add custom download button at specific location in webview. Like following image custom button should add besides copy button

[image]

Comment: Specifically are you using `java` or `kotlin`?

Comment: @JohnMelodyMelissa java

Comment: Great! As answer below :-

Comment: This questions needs to added the #java as well?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the Icon for the `ActionBar` [Follow this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html) with the function as the following,

```java
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Text to copy");
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

For inside the custom (html) `webView` just add:

```js
let copy = (msg) => {
        let textArea = document.createElement("#"); // name of the element
        textArea.value = msg;
        textArea.style.opacity = "0";
        document.body.appendChild(textArea);
        textArea.focus();
        textArea.select();


        try {
            let successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            let msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            alert(msg);
        } catch (err) {
            alert('invalid', error: ' + err.msg);
            }

            document.body.removeChild(textArea);
        };
```

Comment: i want to add button inside webview using script not ourside of webview

Comment: Oh I see, you should had mentioned that specifically.  Wait let me answer the another one.  So do you mean you are planning to use scripting as in `javasciprt` but in inside of webview? Mind explain?

Comment: @JohnMelodyMelissa tbh, he did mention that specifically

Comment: @IvoBeckers, oh? my bad, maybe I misunderstood. Let me read the question again to understand more.

Comment: yes i need to customize webview and add button. Please give me full flow if any example or link how to do that

Comment: @emergingcoders13, will edit my answer in a minute.

Comment: idk whether this helps, it is in javascript. If the website is a custom website then just add this in.